# Did Ichabod Crane's wife Katrina Crane get re-cast during Season One?

Tags: casting, sleepy-hollow-tv

I am watching Sleepy Hollow, and there have been several scenes showing Ichabod's red-haired wife, Katrina Crane. She seems slightly younger in her appearances in the second and subsequent episodes. Her total appearances have been short and made under poor lighting conditions due to her in-show situations.

Was she re-cast after the first episode, or did they just change makeup artists, or am I simply mistaken?

According to some comments on [TV Line](http://tvline.com/2013/09/23/sleepy-hollow-season-1-recap-jenny-mental-institution/), I am not the only one who thinks this, and while some supply that it is the same person, I'd like a confirmation:

> Katrina looks different – or maybe wearing a pound less of makeup. The credits say Katia’s name, but the pilot Katrina looks different from the 2nd episode’s. Was there a recast? *"k" – September 23, 2013*
>
> I thought she looked different too from the pilot (was it her hair colour maybe?), but it’s def the same actress. *JeffDJ – September 23, 2013*
>
> It’s the same actress, but you’re right, she looked different. A big part was the hair. It was more of a flame red in the pilot, and had more body and curl to it. A friend and I watched the pilot before tonight’s ep, and that was the first thing she said when Katrina came on-screen in the second ep. "what happened to her hair?" *Alichat – September 23, 2013*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IMDb claims](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2647544/fullcredits) that it's [Katia Winter](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2316016/) in all six episodes.

You can also check picture albums for [Episode 1](http://katia-winter.net/gallery/thumbnails.php?album=39) and [Episode 2](http://katia-winter.net/gallery/thumbnails.php?album=41) of her fan site. Are these the two looks confusing you?

Comment: If I am not mistaken there is another scene in episode one which is used in the "flashbacks to prior episodes" appearing before each episode; in both her face appears much more gaunt than subsequent episodes.